# Add a REF field with text afterwards in the same location on the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having trouble with what seems like a fairly easy problem. I need to use vba to insert the following sentence at a specific point in a document, the bookmark "FindingsLetter":

"First part of sentence " & {REF field code} & " second part of sentence".

My code is as follows:

```
    withoutFindings = "First part of sentence"
    withoutFindings2 = "second part of sentence"
    Set bm02 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FindingsLetter2").Range.Duplicate
    Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FindingsLetter2").Range.Duplicate
    Set bm03 = ActiveDocument.Range(rngEnd.End, rngEnd.End)
    bm02.InsertBefore (withoutFindings2)
    bm03.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=bm03, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="REF  retirementBoardName \* CHARFORMAT \* MERGEFORMAT", PreserveFormatting:=True
    bm02.InsertAfter (withoutFindings3)
```

I then get the following all after the bookmark:

{REF field} First part of sentence second part of sentence

I tried using offsets such as Set bm03 = ActiveDocument.Range(rngEnd.End + 5, rngEnd.End + 5) but the problem is that the REF field could result in a string with an arbitrary length. I need to somehow tell VBA to "return to the same place that it was at after inserting the REF field"

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way - I am assuming that what you insert should replace anything covered by the bookmark:

```
withoutFindings = "First part of sentence"
withoutFindings2 = "second part of sentence"
' we don't need the .Duplicate here
Set r1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("FindingsLetter2").Range
' insert the first text
r1.Text = withoutFindings

' r2 will mark where we want to put the field code so duplicate r1 and
' colllapse to its end
Set r2 = r1.Duplicate
r2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

' r3 is where our second text will go so just duplicate r2
Set r3 = r2.Duplicate

' insert the second text first so it has the same formatting as the first text
' otherwise it will probably use the formatting of the field's error message
r3.Text = withoutFindings2

' Add the field. NB, PreserveFormatting:=True adds \*Mergeformat anyway
' and you only want one of \*Charformat and \*Mergeformat (and probably neither)
r2.Fields.Add Range:=r2, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="REF retirementBoardName", PreserveFormatting:=True

' You only need this if you need to reinsert the bookmark
r1.SetRange r1.Start, r3.End
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="FindingsLetter2", Range:=r1

' Clean up
Set r3 = Nothing
Set r2 = Nothing
Set r1 = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. I tried to upvote your answer but the system says I dont have enough points or whatever. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @peracsensgrid no problem - you’ll probably be allowed to do that in a day or two